# Gap appearing down the middle

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, rounding-error

**To Reproduce**, To be able to see the gap, the code has to be viewed in these viewports in Chromium based browsers. The gap does not appear in Firefox.

You can set it to different viewports inside jsitor.

**Also**, By increasing and decreasing the browser you're able to see the Gap in the snippet provided. I just checked.

[image]

Click **Run**, not update to test code:

**Further investigating finds:**

**Gap Visible**
https://jsitor.com/ublt2Y43V8

[image]

With YouTube Code Removed, **No Gap Visible.**
https://jsitor.com/XT3U947ICr

Is there a solution to fix this gap issue?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/zPivkcI.png]

**Gap appearing down the middle**

[image]

**From The Snippet:**

[image]

```js
const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
(function manageCurtain() {
  "use strict";

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain-ratio-keeper");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
})();

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";

  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {
    const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";

    new YT.Player(video, {
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist
      },
      events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady,
        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
})();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
  const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
  videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
    show(wrapper);
  }

  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding:8px 6px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.inner{ 
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}
.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.slide-wrap:before,
.slide-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slide-wrap:before {
  left: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.slide-wrap:after {
  right: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.slide .slide-wrap::before {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.slide .slide-wrap::after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
            <div class="video-wrapper">
                <div class="video-ratio-keeper slide-wrap">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="video video-frame"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jacket" title="Play">
                <svg class="play" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
                    <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
              M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reduce this to [mcve], because almost none of that CSS and HTML contributes to the problem. Start removing _everything_ that doesn't contribute to showing this off, and what you're left with is almost certainly already going to let you figure out what's going wrong. But if not, _that_ is the right code to put in a Stackoverflow question. As is: I can't reproduce your problem, and without a problem, there's nothing to help with.

Comment: By increasing and decreasing the browser you're able to see the Gap in the snippet provided. I just checked.

Comment: @buildingcode543 I am not able to see the gap. I am on Firefox.

Comment: I will take a pic.

Comment: I can easily reproduce just by resizing Chrome while running the snippet and inpecting the gap. This is a very well written question from a new contributor. I tried to switch things off and on one by one and could not find the culprit which is likely a pixel division issue that the video pushes the borders 2 pixels to much

Comment: From the snippet here: https://i.imgur.com/F4CKYEh.png

Comment: It is indeed not reproducible on Firefox but easily on Edge and Chrome

Comment: If you make the width of the `:before` and `:after` 51% they will be wide enough to cover the gap when there's a float rounding error without any noticeable impact on the barn door effect when you hit play.

Comment: What about this way:  width: calc(50% + 1px); or is your way better?

Comment: @David That solved it for me

Comment: Did calc(50% + 1px); solve it for you also?

Comment: @buildingcode543 Either one will work. The gap will always be less than 1px, so adding 1px works just fine.

Comment: I went ahead and memorialized this as an answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rounding error with floating points when the width of your container is a non-integer (for example, 241.118px). The `:before` and `:after` elements will fill 50% of the container, but floating point math is imperfect and may round the result incorrectly, so rather than being 120.559px, it may be something like 120.554px. This causes the widths of the two pseudo-elements to not *quite* fill the container all the way, resulting in the gap you're seeing.

A simple, albeit "band-aid-ish" fix is to just increase the width of the two pseudo-elements to something greater than 50% so even if there is a rounding error, the whole container will be covered. I originally suggested 51%, but since the gap will always be less than 1px, you are correct in using `calc(50% + 1px)` as well.

```
.slide-wrap:before,
.slide-wrap:after {

  width: calc(50% + 1px);

}
```